# Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable. If $\int_0^\infty f^2$,$\int_0^\infty f''^2$ converge. Then$\int_0^\infty f'^2 $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Problem:** Let $ f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ be twice continuously differentiable and suppose that $ \int_0^\infty f(x)^2 dx $ , $ \int_0^\infty f''(x)^2 dx $ converge. Then  $ \int_0^\infty f'(x)^2 dx $ converges

**Attempt:**  $ \int_{0}^{ k} f'(x)^2 dx =  \{ u = f' , u = f,  v = f' , v' = f'' \} = f'(x) \cdot f''(x) |_0^k - \int_0^k f\cdot f'' $ [ missing more arguments ].

How can I continue from where I've stopped? It seems to me I need to use some kind of an inequality. If it is Cauchy-Schwartz then I haven't learned about Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality yet, so is there another way?

Edit: Apparently there's the same question here with answers which use Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality: [If $f$ and $f''$ are square integrable is $f'$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633332/if-f-and-f-are-square-integrable-is-f)
But my question is whether it is possible to prove the same theorem without using that inequality? as I haven't learned about it yet in relation to integrals.

Comment: Here is the same question only with $\cal L^1$ integrability: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3867307/42969. I assume that you can proceed similarly.

Comment: Is $ f''$ continious?

Comment: @MartinR I haven't learned about Lebesgue integrability ( and looking at the details of it, there are more things I haven't learned like Fubini-Tonelli theorem ) but In case there'll be no answer, I'll try to follow that question's answer.

Comment: @BotnakovN. You are correct, there was an error in the original question, now $ f $ is twice continuously differentiable

Comment: Apparently there is a simpler answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/633332/42969 (and you were on the right track).

Comment: @MartinR  How can I avoid using Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality? I haven't learned about it in relation to integrals.

Comment: You can use the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean, see the comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633332/if-f-and-f-are-square-integrable-is-f?noredirect=1#comment1334987_633357.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try. I guess my question's a duplicate but I did try searching it before answering (  I didn't shorten my format when searching and probably that's why I haven't seen it )